# O que é o Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP)?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, amp

Por acaso eu acabei lendo em um portal de administração onde falava sobre as tendências de marketing digital para o ano de 2017 e o que mais me chamou a atenção foi o AMP.

O que me levou as perguntas.

- O que AMP?
- Como integrá-lo a um projeto ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Apenas para atualizar o link enviado o site com a documentação e tudo sobre o AMP mudou para: http://amp.dev/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O Google criou o projeto chamado `Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP)`, uma resposta ao Facebook Instant Articles, ao Apple News e ao Twitter Moments — todos os gigantes da tecnologia querendo abocanhar mais um pedaço da web que antes ficava sob o domínio das grandes publicações.
O objetivo do Google com o projeto é garantir que as páginas web carreguem quase que instantaneamente quando o usuário clicar em algum link, criando uma experiência tão rápida e responsiva quanto os aplicativos nativos de celular.

O AMP HTML é basicamente o HTML ampliado com propriedades de AMP personalizadas. O arquivo AMP HTML mais simples tem esta aparência:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="canonical" href="hello-world.html">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
   <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
   <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>Hello World!</body>
</html>
```

Leia mais e conheça a documentação aqui: [AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/pt_br/learn/about-amp/)